# Получить названия типов данных у таблицы в Postgresql на python

Tags: python, база-данных, postgresql

Использую модуль psycopg2 для работы с Postgresql. Там есть вот такая штука

```
cursor.description
```

из которой можно получить только OID типа данных колонки.
Собственно вопрос: Как получить именно название типа (integer, varchar итд)? 
Может есть какая-то функция, которая возвращает название по OID? В документации смотрел, но ничего такого не нашел.

Comment: Мне вспоминается только `\d [имя_таблицы]`. Была ещё какая-то конструкция с SHOW CREATE TABLE но в MySQL (см. http://serverfault.com/questions/231952/is-there-a-mysql-equivalent-of-show-create-table-in-postgres).

Comment: @DimXenon это фишка psql, из адаптера для работы с БД это вряд ли сработает.

Comment: По теме: поищите таблицу `pg_types`. Скорее всего, ваш ответ там.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import psycopg2

if __name__ == '__main__':
    DSN = 'host=HOST port=PORT dbname=DBNAME user=USER password=PASS'

    with psycopg2.connect(DSN) as connection:
        with connection.cursor() as cursor:
            cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME LIMIT 0")
            for i in cursor.description:
                cursor.execute("SELECT typname FROM pg_type WHERE oid={oid}".format(oid=i[1]))
                print("Column name: ", i[0], " Column type: ", cursor.fetchone()[0])
```

Как было указано в комментариях выше, искать надо в таблице pg_type. pg_type - служебная таблица в схеме pg_catalog. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/catalogs.html
В ней хранятся информация обо всех типах данных. Эта таблица может быть полезна, если нужно создать свой собственный тип данных в psycopg2. Подробности: http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/advanced.html#type-casting-of-sql-types-into-python-objects

Также название типа данных можно получить по-другому (опущу мешанину соединений и курсоров):

```
SELECT column_name, data_type FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_schema = 'public' AND table_name = TABLE_NAME
```

Читабельное название типа находится в колонке data_type.
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/infoschema-columns.html
У второго решения есть плюс: тип данных хранится как varchar, тогда как в pg_type тип данных - name. Цитата из документации:

> The name type exists only for the storage of identifiers in the
>   internal system catalogs and is not intended for use by the general
>   user.

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Уверен, автор вопроса был бы благодарен за ваш экспертный комментарий к приведенному выше коду.